# Set w/Log steps to generate a Table

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I'm trying to generate a Table with data with the form

`data=Table[{x1,x2,expr1},{x1,x10,x1f,x1step},{x2,x20,x2f,x2step}]`

In the context of my `expr1`, `x2` results to be a relative value between other two variables. For this reason, I'd like to construct my `Table` with "`Log` steps" for `x2` but reading the docs. I couldn't find a clear solution/example on the matter.

I wonder if `x2step` can be setted in a way the list of possible values for `x2` yields

`{0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000}`

for

`x20 = 0.001`

`x2f = 10^3`

or, for instance

`{0.001, 0.01/2, 0.01, 0.1/2, 0.1, 1/2, 1, 10/2, 10, 100/2, 100, 1000/2, 1000}`

**Question**: is this possible? Any hint to solve the problem?

Comment: For the first case `{x2, 10^Range[-3, 3]}` and for the second `{x2, Join[10^Range[-3, 3], Rest[10^Range[-3, 3]]/2] // Sort}`

Comment: Try: `PowerRange[1/1000, 1000]`